# RSpec test case failing after adding Recaptcha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, recaptcha

I have added a gem recaptcha and implemented it on my sign up and login page.
But few of my test cases are failing. One of the test case is :

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'User sessions', js: true do
  let(:organisation) {
    FactoryGirl.create(:organisation, email_domain: 'example.com')
  }

  let!(:user) {
    FactoryGirl.create(:user,
      email: 'mrbig@example.com',
      password: 'password',
      organisation: organisation)
  }

  scenario 'user signs in and out' do
    visit new_user_session_path

    expect(page).to have_content 'Log in'

    fill_in 'Email', with: 'mrbig@example.com'
    fill_in 'Password', with: 'WRONG'
    click_on 'Log in'

    expect(page).to have_content 'Invalid Email or password.'

    fill_in 'Email', with: 'mrbig@example.com'
    fill_in 'Password', with: 'password'
    click_on 'Log in'

    find('.MenuContent-logout').click

    expect(page).to have_text 'Log in'
  end
end
```

I had added `Recaptcha.configuration.skip_verify_env.push("test")` to my `config/initializers/recaptcha.rb` file but still it fails on my build.

I also added :

```
scenario 'user signs up' do
Users::RegistrationsController.any_instance.stub(:check_captcha).and_return(true)
# Begin signup
visit new_user_registration_path
```

But in both cases I am getting the same error :

[image]

Comment: `save_and_open_page` will show you how the page looks like, Useful for debugging

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was a configuration issue in my build environment. I forgot to add the private and public key from google services to my environment variable.

Hope this helps someone